# nunit tests not discovered in c# solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit

The following is the configuration of my development setup (not that much all of this is required; but i thought i would give this information anyway)

- Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
- Nunit 2.6.3
- Nunit Test Adapter 1.1
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

The solution that I am working on has a number of unit tests written in c# using Nunit. I am logged in as the Administrator. For some reason I cannot view the tests in the test explorer.

1. Upon opening the solution the error message displayed by VS is 
   "Unexpected error detected. Check the output pane for details"
2. The output pane just mentions that there were 0 tests detected
3. I have tried everything from re-installing Nunit, repairing VS, to resetting the IDE and the windows layout. No success.
4. If i login as another user on my laptop, I am ABLE to view the tests in test explorer.

Given point no 4 above, can anyone help me to work my way backwards? Try to find out what the problem might be.

The only other painful option would be to reinstall VS. I dont want it to come to that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Jeroen...there is nothing wrong with the code. These tests are working okay with other team members and when i login as another user....thought i would just emphasise again

Comment: Ah I missed that part, sorry.

Answer (score 27):

Make sure that the nunit test adapter is available in Tools | Extensions & updates.
I had a similar problem because i installed the test adapter as part of a project, I had to explicitly add it in the extensions & updates too.
I hope this is the same problem that you are having here.

Also check this post : 
[Tests magically disappeared from Test Explorer pane in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586586/tests-magically-disappeared-from-test-explorer-pane-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philip. I am using the nuget manager for extensions and this is available in extensions and updates. The surprising part is that if I login as another user on my pc I and open the solution file, I can view, build and run the tests through test explorer. But if I login as the administrator I cannot.

Answer (score 3):

One more thing, make sure the build checkbox is checked in Configuration Manager for your test project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to install NUnit3TestAdapter extension for visual studio ,and you can get it from visual studio marketplace.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter

Answer (score 1):

As Philip mentioned you have to also install Nunit Adapter in **Tools** >> Extensions and Updates and search online for Nunit test adapter and download it, then restart the Visual studio and it should discover all your test and now you can run it too.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the targeted .NET framework of your project is compatible with NUnit and the NUnit Test Adapter.

Fresh from a VSS new install (haven't used VSS in literally years), I failed to spot the build warning that my test project was targeting .NET Standard 2.0 (default setting), whereas NUnit+Adapter instead target .NET Framework 4.x.

I installed .Net Framework 4.8, changed my test project to target Framework 4.8 (Project > Properties > Application > Target Framework), rebuilt the project and the tests appeared in the test explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

As per Philip answer you might need to install NUnit Adapter.

If you change your project framework as I just **replaced NetFramework with .Net 5.0**, restart VS and Run All Tests (Ctrl+R, A) to build your projects and discover all tests.
I also experienced other issues like missing options to import namespaces in the using area at the top of the file.

Answer (score -2):

Just go to the search bar
type %temp%
Delete all the files in the Temp folder
Delete all from recycle bin
Clean project
Build project.