# Setting up unit testing for C++ in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm having trouble trying to set up unit testing. My test class is very simple and looks like this:

```
TEST_CLASS(BlahSpec)
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD(blahFunc)
        {
            int res = doSomething();  // this is what I'm testing
            Assert::AreEqual (42, res, L"Blah", LINE_INFO());
        }
};
```

The project compiles and runs fine. However when I choose TEST > Run > All Tests, I get the following error:

```
Cannot discover test extensions installed by NuGet. The NuGet service is not 
available. Tests may not be found due to missing test adapter extensions
```

Do I have to download a NuGet package to get unit testing for C++? **If so, what NuGet package should I download?** I don't want any fancy third-party package, I just need the Microsoft default thing. However, the NuGet extension manager doesn't show me anything that seems to come from Microsoft.

EDIT: I've picked a NuGet package at random, NUnit3, and installed it. Now I get the following errors:

```
Error: Unable to get runner for this assembly. Check installation, including any extensions.
BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
Assembly not supported: C:\Develop\test-project\projects\Debug\UnitTestApp1\UnitTestApp1.exe
```

As it appears, NUnit3 does not seem the right choice for C++ native unit tests. Which NuGet package should I pick?

Comment: This seems answered here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586586/tests-magically-disappeared-from-test-explorer-pane-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I've read it twice, but I still don't know what test adapter to install.

Comment: I would uninstall and re-install the nuGet package as sort of described in the answers.

Comment: Which nuGet package?

Comment: How did you create the test class?  Did you create a C++ Unit test project? like native?  I didn't have to do anything aside from that.

Comment: I created a new C++ CLI project, referenced the sources from another project from there, and added a new file with the test. I also copied the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.dll into the exe's build folder.